# rails simple_formでチェックボックスが横に並べれない

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

railsでsimple_formを使用しています。チェックボックスを横に並べたいのですができません。以下のようなコードです。

```
= f.input :hoges, label: false, as: :radio_buttons, item_wrapper_class: "inline"
```

http://319ring.net/blog/archives/2167/
こちらを見てitem_wrapper_classを入れたのですがダメです。解決方法がありましたら教えてください。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
form .inline{
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 5px;
}
```

cssを設定することで解決しました。